# Get formated string returns weird result

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a resource manager with the following method

```
fun getString(@StringRes resId: Int, vararg params: Any): String {
    return context.getString(resId, params)
}
```

I call it like this

```
resourceManager.getString(R.string.number_reps, "20")
```

Here is the string:

```
<string name="number_reps">%1$s reps</string>
```

For some reason when i call this method it returns this really weird string:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@5356cf reps
```

Does anyone know why this would happen

**UPDATE**

This worked for me

```
String.format(resourceManager.getString(R.string.number_reps), "20")
```

Comment: You're passing a `vararg` to the `getString` and not the first element (it is treated as an array inside function).  Evidently the `vararg` implementation does not have a toString implementation so you get the `Object` implementation.  The answers are correct about the wrong resource id - but I suspect your post is not correct otherwise it would be a syntax error.

Comment: Post the code that calls and assigns this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong key while accessing the string.

Use this `resourceManager.getString(R.string.number_reps, "20")`

You can also use `String.format` to achieve the same results like below,

`String.format(getString(R.string.number_reps), "20")`

Comment: The wrong key is a typo sorry. I'm calling the correct one. This is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

`resourceManager.getString(R.string.number_repetitions, "20")`

by

```
resourceManager.getString(R.string.number_reps, "20")
```